# Spinner returning null

Tags: android, null, spinner

I have 4 spinners that are returning null and I can't figure out why. I made sure I have the ids right and followed my code that I had used in another activity to make sure it was right but it keeps crashing saying

```
01-25 17:02:47.464: E/AndroidRuntime(13052): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-25 17:02:47.464: E/AndroidRuntime(13052):    at com.skateconnect.AllSpotsActivity$2.onClick(AllSpotsActivity.java:157)
```

the whole code for the class is

```
public class AllSpotsActivity extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> spotsList;
GPSTracker gps;

// url to get all products list
//private static String url_all = "http://72.83.78.137:8080/skate_connect/get_all.php";
private static String url_all = "http://skateconnect.no-ip.biz:8080/skate_connect/get_all.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_SPOTS = "spots";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private int search_trig=0;

// products JSONArray
JSONArray spots = null;

private Spinner spinner_pavement, spinner_traffic, spinner_enviro,spinner_dist;
private String str_pavement, str_traffic, str_enviro,str_dist;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_spots);
    gps = new GPSTracker(AllSpotsActivity.this);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    spotsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    whattosearch();
    //new LoadAllSpots().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();



    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ViewSpotActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {

    spinner_pavement = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_search_pavement);
    spinner_pavement
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    spinner_traffic = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_search_traffic);
    spinner_traffic
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    spinner_enviro = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_search_enviro);
    spinner_enviro
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    spinner_dist = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_dist);
    spinner_dist
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
}

void whattosearch(){
    final Dialog search = new Dialog(this);
    search.setContentView(R.layout.search);
    search.setTitle("What to Search For: ");
    search.setCancelable(false);

    spinner_pavement = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_search_pavement);
    spinner_traffic = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_search_traffic);
    spinner_enviro = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_search_enviro);
    spinner_dist = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_dist);

    Button dialogButton = (Button) search.findViewById(R.id.ButtonOK);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //these are returning null...
            str_pavement = spinner_pavement.getSelectedItem().toString();
            str_traffic = spinner_traffic.getSelectedItem().toString();
            str_enviro = spinner_enviro.getSelectedItem().toString();
            str_dist = spinner_dist.getSelectedItem().toString();
            search_trig=1;
            search.dismiss(); 
            new LoadAllSpots().execute();

        }
      });
    Button dialogSeeAll = (Button) search.findViewById(R.id.ButtonAll);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogSeeAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            search.dismiss(); 
            search_trig=0;
            new LoadAllSpots().execute();
        }
      });
    search.show();
}



// Response from Edit Product Activity
// using longest equation to get least amount of error
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

private double getDistance(double fromLat, double fromLon, double toLat,
        double toLon) {
    Location location1 = new Location("loc1");
    location1.setLatitude(fromLat);
    location1.setLongitude(fromLon);
    Location location2 = new Location("loc2");
    location2.setLatitude(toLat);
    location2.setLongitude(toLon);

    double d = location1.distanceTo(location2) * 0.000621371;// convert to
                                                                // miles
    return d;
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllSpots extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllSpotsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Spots. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        double slat = gps.getLatitude();
        double slong = gps.getLongitude();
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Spots: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                spots = json.getJSONArray(TAG_SPOTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < spots.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = spots.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    double elong = Double.parseDouble(c
                            .getString("longitude"));
                    double elat = Double.parseDouble(c
                            .getString("latitude"));
                    double dist = getDistance(slat, slong, elat, elong);
                    String distance = String.format("%.1f", dist);
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String pave = c.getString("pavement");
                    String traffic = c.getString("traffic");
                    String enviro = c.getString("environment");
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME) + ": " + distance
                            + " Miles Away";
                    //need to create case statement here on search_trig
                    //0 means search all
                    //1 means search by inputs
                    // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put("distance", distance);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        spotsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewSpotActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllSpotsActivity.this, spotsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME, "distance" }, new int[] {
                                R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.distance });
                Collections.sort(spotsList,
                        new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {

                            @Override
                            public int compare(Map<String, String> o1,
                                    Map<String, String> o2) {
                                String value1 = o1.get("distance");
                                String value2 = o2.get("distance");
                                return Double.valueOf(value1).compareTo(
                                        Double.valueOf(value2));
                            }
                        });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}

}
```

If anyone could help me out or point me in the right direction that would be great. I think it might be because the spinners are in a dialog box but I'm not quite sure.

Thank you in advance,

Tyler

EDIT: full logcat

```
01-25 20:21:03.652: E/AndroidRuntime(18730): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 20:21:03.652: E/AndroidRuntime(18730): Process: com.skateconnect, PID: 18730
01-25 20:21:03.652: E/AndroidRuntime(18730): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-25 20:21:03.652: E/AndroidRuntime(18730):    at com.skateconnect.AllSpotsActivity$2.onClick(AllSpotsActivity.java:157)
01-25 20:21:03.652: E/AndroidRuntime(18730):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4452)
01-25 20:21:03.652: E/AndroidRuntime(18730):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18498)
01-25 20:21:03.652: E/AndroidRuntime(18730):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-25 20:21:03.652: E/AndroidRuntime(18730):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-25 20:21:03.652: E/AndroidRuntime(18730):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-25 20:21:03.652: E/AndroidRuntime(18730):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5083)
01-25 20:21:03.652: E/AndroidRuntime(18730):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 20:21:03.652: E/AndroidRuntime(18730):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-25 20:21:03.652: E/AndroidRuntime(18730):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-25 20:21:03.652: E/AndroidRuntime(18730):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-25 20:21:03.652: E/AndroidRuntime(18730):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do all the spinners actually have selected items? According to the docs for `getSelectedItem()` ... **"The data corresponding to the currently selected item, or null if there is nothing selected."**

Comment: 157: spinner_pavement = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_search_pavement);

and I'm fairly sure that something is being selected because I do click on the spinners and click different things

Comment: **"157: spinner_pavement = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_search_pavement);"** - But that doesn't make sense as far as your logcat goes - it shows the NPE is in the `onClick(...)` method "at com.skateconnect.AllSpotsActivity$2.onClick"

Comment: sorry copied the wrong line it is actually 
str_pavement = spinner_pavement.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: In that case there are only two possibilities, either `spinner_pavement` is `null` or `getSelectedItem()` is returning `null`. I suggest you check `spinner_pavement` isn't `null` before calling `getSelectedItem()`. That way you will narrow it down. Also, there will be more to the logcat than what you posted - there'll normally be a "Caused by" section.

Comment: how can I check if its null? and okay I'll update the original post with the full logcat

Comment: id recommend using the debugger to figure out whats null. but since you successfully attached a listener to the spinner im going iwth getSelectedItem() returns null.

Comment: Thats what I'm figuring too but I can't figure out why it would be returning null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following lines in your whattosearch() method...

```
spinner_pavement = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_search_pavement);
spinner_traffic = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_search_traffic);
spinner_enviro = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_search_enviro);
spinner_dist = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_dist);
```

...to use the `findViewById(...)` method of your `Dialog`. Example...

```
spinner_pavement = (Spinner) search.findViewById(R.id.spinner_search_pavement);
```

You seem to have got your wires crossed along the way and you're trying to find the spinners in your activity's content view instead of in the dialog's.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `getApplicationContext()` instead of `parent.getContext()` in your `onItemSelected()` method where you create the `Toast`.

Comment: What does this have to do with a NPE in `onClick(...)` method of the `dialogButton`'s `OnClickListener`?